# How can I change the location of the Android debug key store?

Tags: android

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) says

> To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file. The
>   default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux,
>   in C:\Documents and Settings.android\ on Windows XP, and in
>   C:\Users.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

I'd like to use a debug keystore from another location because `$HOME` isn't writable for the user building the app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the environment variable

```
"ANDROID_SDK_HOME"="C:\your\path\"
```

then you can put the **.android** directory there and the build will search for the debug key there.

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse ...

Just export your project. There will be a step about the keystore.
click "Create new Keystore" and choose your destination

Comment: I'm running `ant` on the command line to build my app. Is there an equivalent setting I can use there?

Comment: take a look at :
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html#DebugMode  
"Build signed and aligned"
They talk about key.store=path/to/my.keystore

Comment: Or you can specify to the jarsigner : 
`jarsigner -keystore c:\folderforyourkeystore\myKeystore.keystore c:\android\projects\myApp\bin\myApp-unsigned.apk myAlias `